# To Extract Substring from Column of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Code Error]

I am trying to extract 4 characters after First,second,third and so on occurance of '/' from Column of Dataframe

[image: DataFrame]

Can someone suggest possible code let me know what is error in my code

Comment: Please post both data and code as *code* and not *screenshots*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
>>> df["NE Name"].str.findall(r"/([^/]{4})")
0                      [01HJ]
1    [01HL, 02HL, 03HL, 10HL]
2    [01HL, 02HL, 03HL, 10HL]
3    [01HL, 02HL, 03HL, 10HL]
4    [01HL, 02HL, 03HL, 10HL]
Name: NE Name, dtype: object
```

###### Input DataFrame:

```
>>> df
                                                     NE Name     Subrack ID  pattern
0   10100000/01HJ   0   01HJ
1   10100000/01HL&10100000/02HL&10100000/03HL&10100000/10HL               1     01HJ
2   10100000/01HL&10100000/02HL&10100000/03HL&10100000/10HL               0     01HJ
3   10100000/01HL&10100000/02HL&10100000/03HL&10100000/10HL               2     01HJ
4   10100000/01HL&10100000/02HL&10100000/03HL&10100000/10HL               3     01HJ
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i have one small query, My objective is to get one new column with New NE. First part of new Column should be characters before first '/' in each row and the remaining part should be characters 4 characters before '&' but twist is if the subrack ID = 0 then it should pick first 4 characters after before occurrence of '&' from NE Name (first column ) and if its 1 then it should pick 4 characters before second occurrence of '&' from NE Name (first column )  ex: 10100000/01HJ with Subrack ID =0 and 10100000/03HL with Subrack ID =2 and 10100000/10HL with Subrack ID =3

Comment: actually i extracted one column already with 1010000 ( before first / ) of rows and second step i though would extract all after '/' 4 characters then thought was using split function along with select to concatanate 1010000 and split.str[0] for first split [1] for second like that.... but based on above result new column generated is object and i am unable to perform split.... sorry for asking simple questions but i just started learning thanks in advance

Comment: This is a completely new question. You should create a new post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic approach without using regular expressions:

1. Use the `str.split('/')` method on the column to return a series of lists, each list containing the substrings in between the slashes.
2. `apply` a function to that series which returns the first four characters of each list element, except the first one. You can use the `lambda` keyword to concisely define such a function within the `apply` call.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['101000000/01HJ', 
    '1010000/01HL&101/02HL&1010/03HL&04/10HL']})

df['col'].str.split('/').apply(lambda seq: [x[:4] for x in seq[1:]])
```

```
0                      [01HJ]
1    [01HL, 02HL, 03HL, 10HL]
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: In my actual DF there was some value with which needs to extracted after & as well thats i used H as point of extraction in my Regex.. thanks really appreciate your first response. Actually i am beginner and still learing python... can you explain logic of lamba so that i can use in any future codes... thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added some explanations. The `lambda` keyword allows you to define an anonymous function within one line. The general syntax is `lambda x: f(x)`, where `f(x)` can be any expression. This can simplify code when you need a particular function in just one place, e.g. as an argument to another function, as above.